# Shouldn't we rather answer/vote on answers instead of downvoting questions on devops.meta?

Tags: discussion

IMHO we should resist the urge of quickly downvoting questions on devops.meta and instead answer or vote on answers - so that the results of the respective discussions (if valuable, of course) remain visible for reference as opposed to being wiped by the roomba only to be asked again later on?.

I mean, for example, questions like [Should we start moving on-topic questions from SO and Serverfault to here?](http://meta.devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3/should-we-start-moving-on-topic-questions-from-so-and-serverfault-to-here)

Comment: The answer shhould be yes, at least according to this SE meta post [A Proposal for More Constructive Downvoting on Meta: Express Disagreement by Answering the Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193884/a-proposal-for-more-constructive-downvoting-on-meta-express-disagreement-by-ans)

Comment: Ideally, yes, but it's hard to change people's behaviour when it's so ingrained.

Comment: Well, the roomba won't remove a downvoted question with upvoted answer IIRC, so there's no real problem giving a position by voting...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this MetaSE post [about auto deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) a question won't be deleted if it has an answer positively scored.

So there's no problem showing disagreement by voting on questions, the worst thing happening to them is that they get out of the devops.meta homepage.

That doesn't remove the need to answer it as best as possible to explain the overall disagreement when it's the case.

Comment: Yep. This makes it a better answer than @avi's.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we should only downvote meta questions themselves if the meta question is poorly asked, or not constructive.